# Use Python to search lines of file for list entries

Tags: python, regex, list, file, search

I have a text file with tens of thousands of lines of ASCII text. I have a list of a few hundred keywords that I want to search for, considering each line individually. Initially, I want to return (print to screen or a file) the line if there are any matches but eventually I'd like to rank or order the returned lines based on how many matches.

So, my list is something like this...

```
keywords = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

My train of thought was something like:

```
myfile = open('file.txt')
for line in myfile:
    if keywords in line:
        print line
```

But taking this from psuedo to working code is not happening.

I've also thought of using RegEx:

```
print re.findall(keywords, myfile.read())
```

But that leads me down a path of different errors and problems.

If anyone can offer some guidance, syntax or code snippets I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test to see if there is a list in a string. What you can do is test is there is a string in another string.

```
lines = ['this is a line without any keywords', 
         'this is a line with one', 
         'this is a line with one and two',
         'this is a line with three']
keywords = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for line in lines:
    for word in keywords:
        if word in line:
            print(line)
            break
```

The `break` is necessary to break out of the "word" loop when the first word is matched. Otherwise it will print the line for each word it matches.

---

The regex solution has the same problem. You can either use the same solution as I did above and add an additional loop over the words, or you can construct a regex that will automatically match any of the words. See the [Python regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) documentation.

```
for line in lines:
    matches = re.findall('one|two|three', line)
    if matches:
        print(line, len(matches))
```

Note that `re.findall` returns an empty list if there are no matches and a list of all the matches if there are matches. So we can directly test the result in the if condition, as empty lists evaluate to `False`.

You can also easily generate the regex pattern for these simple cases:

```
pattern = '|'.join(keywords)
print(pattern)
# 'one|two|three'
```

---

To sort them, you can simply put them in a list of tuples and use the `key` argument of `sorted`.

```
results = []
for line in lines:
    matches = re.findall('one|two|three', line)
    if matches:
        results.append((line, len(matches)))

results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

You can read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sorted) for `sorted`, but the `key` argument provides a function to use for sorting. In this case, we extract the second element of each tuple, which is where we stored the number of matches in that line, and sort the list with that.

---

This is how you might apply this to an actual file and save the results.

```
keywords = ['one', 'two', 'three']
pattern = '|'.join(keywords)

results = []
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches = re.findall(pattern, line)
        if matches:
            results.append((line, len(matches)))

results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line, num_matches in results:
        f.write('{}  {}\n'.format(num_matches, line))
```

You can read up on the [with context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), but in this situation it essentially ensures that you close the file once you're done with it.

Comment: As I have tens of thousands of lines to search and hundreds of search terms I'm really hoping I can find a way for the program to handle this regardless of what file or search list I point it to. Would it be possible to convert each line into a string, perform the search and return it if a match was found?

Comment: @Raitlin Just replace `lines` with whatever file object you're pulling from and use the `pattern = '|'.join(keywords)` to generate the regex pattern from the list of keywords. Though if you have enough lines that storing them all in memory at once is an issue then there are other ways to process, sort, and save the lines in batches to save on memory.

Comment: @Raitlin I'm not sure I understand you. When reading files, I think by default it will read each line in as a string.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Python so I don't know what the default action is. If it already considers each line as a string I should be able to read the line, check for matches, if match do some action then go on to the next line. In addition to the problems I'm having I have the additional issue of not phrasing my question well because I don't know the terminology enough.

Comment: @Raitlin I hope the last edit putting it all together works for you/helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help and patience. Can I just throw <print results> at the end to see the matches (No, I just tried, lol)? I think I'm following the logic but I'll have to lookup things like ".append" to understand what should be happening. Maybe I need to understand this by having it return matches as they are found, the sorting seems to complex as I don't have enough understanding of the language. I'm really going down the rabbit hole here, lol.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Not sure why you can't.

Comment: Let me clarify then. It returns empty square brackets. Other than your code block, I've only added 'import re', my full keyword list and the 'print results' at the very end. Of course, I've edited the file name to read as well. I've confirmed that in the list to search, a couple thousand entries down, is a line with at least 2 of the items from my keyword list.

Comment: You might want to try with a simple test case first to isolate the problem, as it's working for me with one. I'm not sure what the issue could be, though keep in mind that regex is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yeah, good call. So, cutting my keyword list to 2 items still did nothing. I created a new file with only a few lines and it works great with the short and the full keyword list. So, the problem has something to do with my file. Is it possible it's just too big or could there be some type of character or formatting issue? Kudos on the code though, now that I see it working it's very nice.

Comment: Too big shouldn't be an issue unless you're running out of memory or something (which would be obvious). A character of formatting issue is possible. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I got it working. My file has 93,000+ lines but I didn't think that was an issue. It has lots of random ASCII, both printable and non-printable. I used the TextFX plugin for Notepad++ to replace all non-printable characters with a '#' symbol. It worked great at this point, returning a couple thousand results as expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) from the [collections module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) seems like a great fit for the problem. I would do something like this.

```
from collections import Counter

keywords = ['one', 'two', 'three']
lines = ['without any keywords', 'with one', 'with one and two']

matches = []
for line in lines: 
    # Takes all the words in the line and gets the number of times 
    # they appear as a dictionary-like Counter object.
    words = Counter(line.split())

    line_matches = 0
    for kw in keywords:
        # Get the number of times it popped up in the line
        occurrences = words.get(kw, 0)
        line_matches += occurrences

    matches.append((line, line_matches))

# Sort by the number of occurrences per line, descending.
print(sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
```

This outputs:

```
[('with one and two', 2), ('with one', 1), ('without any keywords', 0)]
```

Comment: I like that to rank the results but I still think I have the problem of having this code work against a big file and a list of hundreds of keywords. Entering the keywords manually in the code is no problem but I can't do that with the material to search...it's 10,000+ lines. Again, I wonder if there is a way to read a line, convert to string, do what I need to do, etc. Maybe a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify it in your question, but according to me if a single keyword is found multiple times, it should count only one for the score (this advantages lines with more different keywords):

```
def getmatching(lines, keywords):
    result = []
    keywords = set(keywords)
    for line in lines:
        matches = len(keywords & set(line.split()))
        if matches:
            result.append((matches, line))
    return (line for matches, line in sorted(result, reverse=True))
```

### Example

```
lines = ['no keywords here', 'one keyword here',
         'two keywords in this one line', 'three minus two equals one',
         'one counts only one time because it is only one keyword']

keywords = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for line in getmatching(lines, keywords):
    print line
```

*Output*

```
three minus two equals one
two keywords in this one line
one keyword here
one counts only one time because it is only one keyword
```