# Use a file to search lines in another file in Python

Tags: python, search

I have two files: one has one word per line and the other has 3; they look like this:

List file:

```
Gene1
Gene2
Gene3
Gene4
```

Master file:

```
Gene8   Gene3   2.1
Gene10  Gene5   3
Gene1   Gene20  2.1
Gene3   Gene2   3.3 
Gene48  Gene95  2
```

So what I want is to use the List file to search and extract the lines in the Master file that match with the List and write them in a third New file. So the desired output would be:

New file:

```
Gene8   Gene3   2.1
Gene1   Gene20  2.1
Gene3   Gene2   3.3
```

I've tried using regular expressions to use re.search, but I didn't seem to get it correct as it was always writing the whole document in case of matches, rather than the individual matching lines.

I tried loading the files and converting them to string and with a double for loop but it looks like it is matching letter by letter intead of by words, which makes the output file quite difficult to manage.

Yes, I saw the post [Use Python to search lines of file for list entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291902/use-python-to-search-lines-of-file-for-list-entries/25292064#25292064) but I cant make it work properly and the resulting files need still more formating that make the process complicated and I seem to be losing some info (List file has thousands of entries and Master file is several hundred of thousand of lines so it is not easy to keep track of).

I come to you as I know there should be a way more efficient and easy way to do because it needs to be run several times

Comment: How big is list file, as compared to your RAM ?

Comment: How about `grep -f ListFile MasterFile > NewFile`? (Add a space in the end of each line in `ListFile` to avoid matching `Gene10`, `Gene20` or `Gene48`)

Comment: You can add a space at the end of each line with `sed 's/$/ /' oldfile > newfile`

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Mmm 6k long with 4GB RAM

Comment: @timrau Yes I was told grep would do the trick simply, though I dont have acces to a UNIX computer, so I figured that if it was simple enough in UNIX there should be a simple enough solution in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the keyword list into a set:

```
keywords = set()
with open(list_file_path) as list_file:
    for line in list_file:
        if line.strip():
            keywords.add(line.strip())
```

Then iterate over each line in the master file, pulling out the lines that contain at least one keyword:

```
with open(master_file_path) as master_file:
    with open(search_results_path, 'w') as search_results:
        for line in master_file:
            if set(line.split()[:-1]) & keywords:
                search_results.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working fine and efficiently, and understandable enough :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I used both of the sample data files that you provided and the code below provides the desired output that you posted. If this process is going to be repeated often and you need to speed it up then you might want to consider using a different search algorithm. If this is the case then just let me know what operations will be most common(inserting into list, searching the list, deleting items in the list), and we can use the most appropriate search algorithm.

```
# open the list of words to search for
list_file = open('list.txt')

search_words = []

# loop through the words in the search list
for word in list_file:

    # save each word in an array and strip whitespace
    search_words.append(word.strip())

list_file.close()

# this is where the matching lines will be stored
matches = []

# open the master file
master_file = open('master.txt')

# loop through each line in the master file
for line in master_file:

    # split the current line into array, this allows for us to use the "in" operator to search for exact strings
    current_line = line.split()

    # loop through each search word
    for search_word in search_words:

        # check if the search word is in the current line
        if search_word in current_line:

            # if found then save the line as we found it in the file
            matches.append(line)

            # once found then stop searching the current line
            break

master_file.close()


# create the new file
new_file = open('new_file.txt', 'w+')

# loop through all of the matched lines
for line in matches:

    # write the current matched line to the new file
    new_file.write(line)

new_file.close()
```

Comment: There is not much operations other than that the search and extract. It does work though it is a bit slow for such big files. That is some very neat commented code!